# Error in response while trying to create and add new data in mongodb database

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, validation, mongoose

getting the following error while sending a request from postman
I am trying to create a hotel but when I send my post request to the server I am getting this response saying 500 internal server error.I am not able to find any error in the code .Can anyone tell me what's the issue.
I am sending this request

localhost:8000/api/hotel

```
       {
"errors": {
    "cheapestPrice": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `cheapestPrice` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `cheapestPrice` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "cheapestPrice"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "cheapestPrice"
    },
    "desc": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `desc` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `desc` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "desc"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "desc"
    },
    "title": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `title` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `title` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "title"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "title"
    },
    "distance": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `distance` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `distance` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "distance"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "distance"
    },
    "address": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `address` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `address` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "address"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "address"
    },
    "city": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `city` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `city` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "city"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "city"
    },
    "type": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `type` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `type` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "type"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "type"
    },
    "name": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `name` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `name` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "name"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "name"
    }
},
"_message": "Hotel validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "Hotel validation failed: cheapestPrice: Path `cheapestPrice` is required., desc: Path `desc` is required., title: Path `title` is required., distance: Path `distance` is required., address: Path `address` is required., city: Path `city` is required., type: Path `type` is required., name: Path `name` is required."
```

}

this is the model Hotel.js file

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const {Schema} = mongoose

const HotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    type:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    address:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    distance:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    photos:{
        type:[String],
        
    },
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    desc:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
   
    rating:{
        type: Number,
     min:0,
     max:5
    },
    rooms:{
        type:[String]
        
    },
// for showing cheapest hotels
    cheapestPrice:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    // for showing featured hotels
    featured:{
        type:Boolean,
        deafult:false,
    }



})

export default mongoose.model("Hotel",HotelSchema)
```

This is the route hotel.js

```
import express from "express"
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";
const router = express.Router();


router.post("/", async (req,res)=>{

const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body);

    try{
        const savedHotel = await newHotel.save()
        res.status(200).json(savedHotel)

}catch(err){
res.status(500).json(err)
}

})
export default router
```

This is the main index.js file

```
import express from "express"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import hotelRoute from './routes/hotels.js'

const app = express()
dotenv.config()

const connect = async () =>{

    try{

await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO)
console.log("Connected to mongodb")
    }catch(err){
        throw err;

    }
}
mongoose.connection.on("connected",()=>{
    console.log("mongodb connected")
})
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected",()=>{
    console.log("mongodb disconnected")
})


//Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json())


app.use("/api/hotel",hotelRoute)

app.listen(8000,() =>{
    connect()
    console.log("Connected to backend")
})
}
```

In the console I'm getting

```
Connected to backend
mongodb connected
Connected to mongodb
```

Comment: some of the fields are required and sounds like you did not send those fields.
please send your request curl

Comment: @MohammadJavad   This is the data which I am sending .. not able to figure out what's missing    {
    "name": "lineage",
    "type": "hotel",
    "city": "lucknow",
    "address": "near balaji road",
    "distance": "200kms",
    "title": "Razzuma Hotel",
    "desc": "Best hotel in the city",
    "cheapestPrice": 100
}         I am still getting this error mentioning for every property that is provided the error is defining its subproperties like

"title": {
    "name" :valiadtion error
     "msg" : path "title" is required 
 }

Comment: const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body);
After this line, log in to the 'newHotel' and see that the model is filled correctly :
console.log("newHotel",newHotel);

Answer (score 0):

first you must check your req.body data.
you can validate your req.body with [joi validator](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0)

and (or) [express-joi-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi-validation).

in [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) you must generate a model from your schema:

```
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

Comment: This is the data I am sending ... not able to figure out what's missing

Comment: const     tried out this      Hotel= mongoose.model("Hotel",HotelSchema)    but still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

The post method URL = http://localhost:8800/api/hotels

try using http://

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32716208)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the POST method via Postman.
The same issue happened to me. The thing I was missing is the data-type to JSON.

You might be sending the request as data-type text.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with same project but I got result with 200 status by doing

```js
res.status(200).json(hotels);
```

In `hotels.js` file everywhere in all GET,PUT,POST,DELETE methods instead of

```js
req.send(200) *or* req.send(500)
```

Hope this finds useful!! Thank you !

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34673343)